# memcache trick - choosing the ideal key

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have to create an application in PHP which will store the phone contacts of different users.

The table for storing the phone numbers is of the following format:

```
id,user-id,phone-number
```

Whenever an user tries to view all his contacts, first of all the contents from the cache should be shown and then the remaining ones from the database.

In implementing this, I have the following problem:

How to store the phone numbers in the cache? By this I mean what should be the key for inserting the phone numbers into memcache so that I can easily extract the data from it for any user. Remember, each user can have many phone numbers and there are many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key should use user id

```
user id { mobile number ... + list of contact ...[which is the user id]} 
// by accessing this key able to get all mobile number
// and his contact list
```

suggestion value should be as simple as possible,
no JSON, no serialize data

```
user id {m:xxx,xxxx..., c:yyy,yyy,yyy}
```

this is to save spaces and also save processing for `json_decode / unserailize`

when getting all contacts for an user

```
1. fetch cache using user id (one call)
2. iterate the list of contact
3. fetch parellel of all the contact (user) key * function handling
4. iterate to build a multi dimensional array
```

when user adding/update/delete a mobile number,
or adding/update/delete a mobile number

```
1. fetch cache using user id (one call)
2. expire the key using user id
3. iterate the cache result
```

your function should be if cache not exist in memcache,
fetch from database,
set memcache,
return the database result

Comment: When adding a new number for a particular user, do i need to delete the cache entry for that user-id and then add the new list? Similarly for delete, should i delete the entire entry from the cache and add the new list for that ID?

Comment: Yes, any changes to an user, you need to expire his cache in order to preserve the data freshness. Once cache not found, fetch from database, set it to memcache

Answer (score 0):

cache key format should be

`12_contacts` where 12 is is the user id.

inside the key you would store the full list of contacts for that user as an array.  generally this means that whenever the users contacts change you either clear or rebuild the memcache key.  you need to store the full contact list inside the key as an array, storing a partial list and then querying for any others defeats the purpose.

Comment: But if the user has too many contacts to fit in the 1MB space to store the value corresponding to a key, what to do then?

Comment: buy more hard drive space.  the purpose of memcache is speed, and memcache requires drive space.